# How can I find questions that have been strongly supported by the community?

Tags: discussion

Background: I was reading up another question on Meta today, when I found a link to this question: [Why is it faster to process a sorted array than an unsorted array?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11227809/6216002).

This question has 14,901 upvotes and the the accepted answer has 20,697 upvotes as of this writing. The sheer number of upvotes shows that the question and the answer are of exceptional standard, as deemed by the SO community.

So my question is: How can I find more questions like these?

Comment: [All questions asked all time sorted by votes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/votes)

Comment: Or http://stackoverflow.com/questions?sort=votes if you're not using the new navigation.

Comment: "the question and the answer are of exceptional standard" Possibly, but it is more likely a result of compound interest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends how you define *support* but if the [default searches](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/votes) don't satisfy your need you can always head to [SEDE](https://data.stackexchange.com/) and create or find a query that matches your curiousness. For example [this query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/505102):

```sql
with qscore as
(
select top 100 row_number() over (order by score desc) as row
, 'site://q/'+ cast(id as nvarchar) +'|' + title as [By question score]
from posts
where posttypeid = 1 -- Q 
order by score desc
)
, 
ascore as (
select top 100 row_number() over (order by p.score desc) as row
, 'site://q/'+ cast(p.id as nvarchar) +'|' + q.title as [By Answer score]
from posts p
inner join posts q on q.id = coalesce(p.parentid, p.id)
where p.posttypeid = 2 -- A
order by p.score desc
)
,
upvotes as (
select top 100 row_number() over (order by upvote desc) as row
, 'site://q/'+ cast(id as nvarchar) +'|' + title as [By Upvotes]
from (
select top 100 
       p.id
     , case when p.posttypeid = 1 then 'Q: '
       when p.posttypeid =2 then 'A: '
       end + q.title as title
     , count(*) as upvote
from posts p
inner join posts q on q.id = coalesce(p.parentid, p.id)
inner join votes v on v.postid = p.id
where v.votetypeid = 2 -- up mod
group by p.id, q.title, p.posttypeid
order by count(*) desc
) as alldata
order by upvote desc
)
,
downvotes as (
select top 100 row_number() over (order by upvote desc) as row
, 'site://q/'+ cast(id as nvarchar) +'|' + title as [By Downvotes]
from (
select top 100 
       p.id
     , case when p.posttypeid = 1 then 'Q: '
            when p.posttypeid = 2 then 'A: '
       end + q.title as title
     , count(*) as upvote
from posts p
inner join posts q on q.id = coalesce(p.parentid, p.id)
inner join votes v on v.postid = p.id
where v.votetypeid = 3 -- down mod 
group by p.id, q.title, p.posttypeid
order by count(*) desc
) as alldata
order by upvote desc
)
/* -- give me powerz
,
cte_comments as 
(
select top 100 row_number() over (order by count(*) desc) as row
, 'site://q/'+ cast(p.id as nvarchar) +'|' + q.title as [By Comments]
from posts p
inner join posts q on q.id = coalesce(p.parentid, p.id)
inner join comments c on p.id = c.postid
group by p.id, q.title
order by count(*) desc
)
*/

select qs.row
      , qs.[By Question score]
      , ans.[By answer score]
      , uv.[By upvotes]
      , dv.[By Downvotes]
   --   , cm.[By Comments]
from qscore qs
inner join ascore ans on ans.row = qs.row
inner join upvotes uv on uv.row = qs.row
inner join downvotes dv on dv.row = qs.row
-- inner join cte_comments cm on cm.row = qs.row
order by qs.row
```

It produces the question and aswers that attracted a lot of community support in score and votes (up and down). I tried to include the posts with the most comments as well but the Sql Server started to hate me.

A screenshot of the result when run today:

[image: sede results]